# Using Devexpress ASP.NET controls with Delphi Prism

Tags: asp.net, delphi, devexpress, delphi-prism, oxygene

Has anybody had any hands-on experience using Devexpress ASP.NET components with Delphi Prism? At the moment I'm specifically interested in using their "Calendar and Scheduling for ASP.NET" suite.

Sharing your pros/cons, successes/failures would be greatly appreciated.

I'm looking leverage my knowledge of Delphi (and my ownership of RAD Studio).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ken, i think wich is best  use the delphi tag for this kind of questions because gain more visibility. and most of the delphi prism users are delphi programmers too ;)

Comment: @RRUZ  Thank you very much!  I didn't think I had to explain/justify the tags I pick for my question - your comment was exactly correct.

Comment: I was really hoping for a more vibrant/active Prism community.  Lack of response to this question really makes me re-think using Prism. I really do want to give it a far chance. I think it's a great path for veteran Delphi developers. :(

Comment: @RRUZ: Great. So following that logic, rhazell should also add VB.NET and C# tags, because the people using the DevEx controls use those languages, and SQL-Server because many of the ASP.NET applications use it for data storage on the back end? The question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi except that they're from the same company, and @rhazell seems to be a new member here at SO who should learn how to properly tag posts. :-)

Comment: @rhazell: Perhaps just not many people use the combination of Prism and the DevEx controls you're asking for help with? Also, have you asked the question in other places like the DevEx forums (don't have the URL handy) or at the Embarcadero Prism forums at https://forums.embarcadero.com/category.jspa?categoryID=51 ?

Comment: @Ken White: Thanks for the suggestions :). I had started with DevExpress KB (no questions, just searching existing posts) and apparently they don't "officially support" Prism.  That said, there's still a very good chance it works and I was hoping I could find people who could confirm or deny before I went to far down the path. The fact that this post has not received one single answer speaks volumes, in my opinion.  Sidebar: I succesfully used D2005/6 to create ASP.NET apps and I used several 3rd-party .NET that never supported Delphi and they worked fine - part of the beauty of .NET Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that some of our customers use Prism as a platform for the ASP.NET development.  However, we do not officially support this platform and thus won't be able to help you if you run into troubles.  Please also refer to

[Delphi Prism - ASP.NET](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q159889.aspx)